# How to apply For-Each Loop on Argument Array in Functions in Java Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function, object

My Code It Does Not Work.
I want to Sum of Numbers that the user gives in arguments.

So I use here Argument Object but am unable to fetch what is the mistake.

```
    // The Argument Object 
function myFunc()
{
    console.log("You give Total Numbers : "+arguments.length);
    let sum = 0;

    console.log("Sum is : ");
    arguments.forEach(element => {
        sum += element;
    });


    console.log(sum);
}

myFunc(10,20);
myFunc(10,20,30);
myFunc(10,20,30,40);
```

Comment: `arguments` isn't exactly an array, it doesn't have the forEach function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 1):

You could try this solution:

```js
/**
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments
 *
 * @param  {array} args ...args is the rest parameters. It contains all the arguments passed to the function.
 */
function myFunc (...args) {
  console.log(`You give Total Numbers : ${args.length}`);
  /**
   * Reduce is a built-in array method that applies a function against an accumulator and each element
   * in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.
   *
   * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
   */
  const sum = args.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
  console.log('Sum is :', sum);
};

myFunc(10, 20);
myFunc(10, 20, 30);
myFunc(10, 20, 30, 40);
```

**Output**

```js
You give Total Numbers : 2
Sum is : 30
You give Total Numbers : 3
Sum is : 60
You give Total Numbers : 4
Sum is : 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunc(...arguments)
{
    console.log("You give Total Numbers : "+arguments.length);

    console.log("Sum is : ");
     let sum = 0;
    arguments.forEach(element => {
        sum += element;
    });


    console.log(sum);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you name it something other than `arguments` since it is not allowed as an identifier in regular functions in strict mode. A common practice is to name it `args`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function myFunc() {
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    sum += arguments[i];
}
console.log(
    `
    Total Number : ${arguments.length}
    Sum : ${sum}
    `
);

}

myFunc(10 , 20 , 30 , 40);
```

out put like this :

```
Total Number : 4
Sum : 100
```